# Best IDE for GUI in KDE?

Tags: linux, user-interface, kde-plasma

In Windows, I use VS.NET with C# because it supports most of the newest functionalities of Windows User Interface.
Similarly, MAC, I use XCode with CoCoa.

I wonder if there is anything for KDE?

Java Swing and Qt are cross-platform GUI, and they tried to port the common funcitonalities but not all. I'm looking for the one which dedicated for KDE.

Thanks.

Comment: This is purely opinion based... You would get too many answers to find useful information out of such a thread like this... Best if you try yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two of the popular Qt IDE's are:

- [QtCreator](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category%3aTools%3a%3aQtCreator)
- [KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/)

And, of course, you can use any other IDE that will compile C++ code, so there's always:

- [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/)
- [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)

Comment: If you want an easy one I always vote NetBeans

Comment: You have not mentioned vi!!! :D